How to notarize a CLI program for macOS?
I am building a cli program with Go that I sign and notarize. There are 2 areas of confusion for me.

Is it correct that CLI programs can't have tickets stapled to them? Meaning, I can zip my cli program and send it to the notarization service, but in contrary to app bundles, I cannot staple a ticket to them?

As mentioned, I signed and notarized my CLI app. codesign confirms this for me. However, when I upload it to my website, and download it and unzip it with the builtin unzip tool, I get this error message upon running it:



I even tried to sign and notarize a DMG, still with the same behaviour. It all works if I remove the quarantine flag from my program.
How can I distribute my CLI program without the obstacles of telling the user to remove the quarantine flag?
P.S. Alternatively, I could offer a workaround using an installation step using curl as it doesn't create a quarantine flag on the zip either. However, that as well is a weird UX hurdle.

I would recommend you check out https://orth.uk/macos-clis/

Thanks, unfortunately the error message is different and the Right click > Open trick doesn't work anymore

Sure, but the rest of the article still applies right?
